# Inserting row in the middle of SQL table and adjusting ascending id's

Tags: php, sql

I wish to allow insertion of rows in the middle of a sql table and afterwards automaticly update the ascending id's to be +1.

Example:

```
ROW  ID
1    5
2    6
3    7
4    8
```

I then want to be able to insert a 5th row with the id of 6, and make the other rows update to be +1 of their current number:

```
ROW  ID
1    5
2    7
3    8
4    9
5    6
```

Is there an efficient way to this? other than running through the whole table and adjusting the other id's to +1?

Comment: given that all the ID's do have to be modified, something of the sort of `UPDATE TABLE SET ID=ID+1 WHERE ID > InsID` should be a decent option

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to the `ID` column. That way you only need to run through the rows that are actually affected by the update operation instead of though the whole table. On the downside, each index makes inserts more expensive.

BTW Don't change `ID` entries if the `ID` column belongs to your primary key.

Comment: This id wont be my primary key, as this is just for outputting the data correct.
Could you give me an example of how the sql code should look with this id as index.